# Deploying web.py project to Bluehost, WSGIServer: missing FastCGI error

Tags: linux, python, webserver, deployment, htaccess

I'm trying to deploy a very simple web.py app to my Bluehost website using [these instructions.](https://github.com/stevekochscience/webpy-bluehost-helloworld) Here's my main python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import web
from web import form

import whitelistchecker

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = ('/', 'index')
app = web.application(urls, globals())

myform = form.Form( 
    form.Textarea('whitelist', description = "", rows = 10, cols = 50)
)

output = None

class index: 
    def GET(self): 
        form = myform()
        return render.inputform(form, output)

    def POST(self): 
        form = myform() 
        if not form.validates(): 
            return render.inputform(form, output)
        else:
            return render.inputform(form, whitelistchecker.ReportRejectedSevere(form['whitelist'].value))

web.wsgi.runwsgi = lambda func, addr=None: web.wsgi.runfcgi(func, addr)

if __name__=="__main__":
    web.internalerror = web.debugerror
    app.run()
```

It runs fine locally without the `web.wsgi.runwsgi` line.

Here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
allow from all
SetHandler fcgid-script
Options +ExecCGI
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ interface.py/$1 [PT]
```

It's exactly the same as in the tutorial. Both of these files are in the same directory in my `public_html` directory, with some other files for this app (templates and utilities-- not related to deployment). I am getting these errors:

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
Status: 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
```

I'm not sure how to fix that. Help is appreciated. I also couldn't get the exact same code as the tutorial to run, so I don't think  it's *just* my code.